# Powering an IR + RED laser with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, diodes, resistance, laser

I am hoping to run a laser diode from an Arduino.
The specific one with included data sheets are here:
 https://industrial.panasonic.com/kr/products/semiconductors/laser/red_infrared/red-and-infrared-ir-laser-diodes/LNCT28PS01WW

It seems the red component operates at 2.4V 128mA and the IR component operates at 2.5V 210mA. I've done some calculations and arrived at 20 ohms for the red and 10 ohms for the IR series connections, but I am wondering if there are any considerations I need to make since they are both integrated. What would my circuit diagram look like?

Is it reasonable/feasible to operate this laser from an Arduino, or do I need to look for another source with a fixed current?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a photodiode (PD) is used to
monitor the power. The signal from the
PD will be fed back to the current source
to maintain the output power from LD at a
constant level.

Depending on the application type, LD
driving current source should be selected,
from the viewpoints of maximum current,
maximum voltage, and with or without
modulation and APC function.
[REF](https://industrial.panasonic.com/content/data/SC/ds/ds8/c2/APN_Laser_CAN-PKG_AppNote_EN.pdf)
Read about it.

**CC regulator designs are easily found.** Use the PD current to detect laser power using the PD current converted to voltage in a load resistor of your choice with an Op AMp and FET with a stable reference voltage.

The reason for this is although the forward voltage rises with current, it falls with higher temps quickly so overvoltage and thus overcurrent can more easily damage the LASER diode than an LED due to additional nonlinear lasing effects and component tolerances with thermal cooling required.

Answer (score 1):

Three things I'd watch out for:

- Looking at the I-L and I-V curves, when the red laser is outputting 100 mW, you will be putting in about 400 mW of electrical energy. That means ~300 mW being converted to heat.  (and another 300 mW from the IR LED if it's operating at a similar power level) If you aren't operating this thing in a low duty cycle pulse mode, you'll want to provide some kid of cooling to keep it at a reasonable temperature.
- Bare laser diodes like these can be damaged very quickly, like within microseconds, by overvoltage or overcurrent events. For this reason we normally drive them with circuits that protect the device from over-voltage, over-current, ESD, and other hazards. If you search for laser driver circuits you will find many suggestions how to do this.

  Although I don't know about this laser specifically, or about the Arduino's power supply circuit, my first guess is that you don't want to power the laser directly from the Arduino with just a series resistor to limit the current.
- Anything over 5 mW is getting into the range where you could damage your eyes with a laser beam. 200 mW total between the two lasers here could do damage before you're even aware you've looked into the beam. Be sure to take appropriate precautions when operating these lasers.